# Is there a way to extend Sql Server so that the "like" operator would rather execute a full-text search?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use Entity Framework and that really complicates the way I do full-text searches. It's possible but it's not straight-forward.

The ideal solution would be a way to extend Sql Server in such a way that regular like expressions would be treated as full-text search or something like that.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use fulltext predicates in the WHERE...(such as "CONTAINS", etc.).  Like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx